# get count and reporting persons details

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: "emp" is the child column and "man" is the parent column. I need to count the total number of children ( direct/indirect) for any given parent.

```
emp         man
23ank(5*)   213raj(11*)
55man(5*)   213raj(11*)
2shu(1*)    23ank(5*)
7am(3*)     55man(5*)
9shi(0*)    55man(5*)
213raj(11*) 66sam(13*)
```

The solution I am looking for is if, for instance, I want the details related to 213raj(11*), then:

```
213raj(11*),23ank(5*),2shu(1*),55man(5*),7am(3*),9shi(0*)
```

and the total count for 213raj(11*) =5.

If I consider 66sam(13*) then:

```
66sam(13*),213raj(11*),23ank(5*),2shu(1*),55man(5*),7am(3*),9shi(0*)
```

and the total count for 66sam(13*) =6

I tried the code below but am not getting the required results:

```
kv = kvpp[['emp','man']]
kvp = dict(zip(kv.emp,kv.man))

parents = set()
children = {}
for c,p in kvp.items():
    parents.add(p)
    children[c] = p

def ancestors(p):
    return (ancestors(children[p]) if p in children else []) + [p]

pp = []
for k in (set(children.keys()) - parents):
    pp.append('/'.join(ancestors(k)))
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is the logic behind finding a parent's children and what is the significance of the number in brackets? `(11*)` Also could you provide what output are you getting with your current code?

Comment: Also, in future please improve your question title, see the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, this function should give you the correct answers:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'emp':['23ank(5*)', '55man(5*)', '2shu(1*)', '7am(3*)', '9shi(0*)', '213raj(11*)'],
                   'man':['213raj(11*)', '213raj(11*)', '23ank(5*)', '55man(5*)', '55man(5*)', '66sam(13*)']})


def count_children(parent):
    total_children = []  # initialise list of children to append to
    direct = df[df['man'] == parent]['emp'].to_list()
    total_children += direct  # add direct children

    indirect = df[df['man'].isin(direct)]['emp'].to_list()
    total_children += indirect  # add indirect children

    # next, add children of indirect children in a loop
    next_indirect = indirect
    while True:
        next_indirect = df[df['man'].isin(next_indirect)]['emp'].to_list()
        if not next_indirect or all(i in total_children for i in next_indirect):
            break
        else:
            total_children = list(set(next_indirect).union(set(total_children)))

    count = len(total_children)
    return pd.DataFrame({'count':count,
                     'children':','.join(total_children)},
                     index=[parent])
```

`count_children('213raj(11*)')` -> 5

`count_children('66sam(13*)')` -> 6

Comment: Yes ,this is the one part of result i am looking for. This if i get in dataframe with '213raj(11*)' in column, 5 as count in another column and list of all 5 childs (direct/indirect) with comma separated in last column. will help me

Answer (score 2):

In graph theory terms, you have an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) forming a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

Here's a solution using the [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) graph theory library.

```py
import networkx as nx

emp_to_man = [
 ('23ank(5*)', '213raj(11*)'),
 ('55man(5*)', '213raj(11*)'),
 ('2shu(1*)', '23ank(5*)'),
 ('7am(3*)', '55man(5*)'),
 ('9shi(0*)', '55man(5*)'),
 ('213raj(11*)', '66sam(13*)'),
]

# Create a directed graph using the adjacency matrix.
# Converting a 2-column DF into a digraph is as easy as
# `nx.DiGraph(list(df.values))`.
g = nx.DiGraph(emp_to_man)

for emp in sorted(g):  # For every employee (in sorted order for tidiness),
     # ... print the set of ancestors (in no particular order).
     # Should the adjacency matrix be `man_to_emp` instead, you'd use `
     print(emp, nx.ancestors(g, emp))
```

This prints out

```
213raj(11*) {'55man(5*)', '7am(3*)', '2shu(1*)', '9shi(0*)', '23ank(5*)'}
23ank(5*) {'2shu(1*)'}
2shu(1*) set()
55man(5*) {'9shi(0*)', '7am(3*)'}
66sam(13*) {'213raj(11*)', '55man(5*)', '7am(3*)', '9shi(0*)', '2shu(1*)', '23ank(5*)'}
7am(3*) set()
9shi(0*) set()
```

**EDIT**: In case performance is paramount, I'd heartily suggest the NetworkX approach. Based on a quick `timeit` test, finding all the employees is roughly 62 times faster than the Pandas-based code, and that's converting the DF into an NX network on every invocation.

**EDIT 2**: To my rather great surprise, a naïve set/defaultdict graph traversal is faster still -- 387 times faster than the Pandas code and 5 times faster than the Nx code above.

```
def dag_count_all_children():
    dag = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for man, emp in df.values:
        dag[emp].add(man)
    out = {}

    for man in set(dag):
        found = set()
        open = {man}
        while open:
            emp = open.pop()
            open.update(dag[emp] - found)
            found.update(dag[emp])

        out[man] = found
    return out
```